# ¿Cómo puedo insertar el espacio en este cifrado césar?

Tags: javascript

Soy un poco novata en esto, y probablemente la respuesta sea obvia, pero no consigo hacer que mi código imprima el texto con espacios. He utilizado el cifrado césar.

Cuando imprime mediante consola lo hace todo pegado sin espacios ni caracteres especiales.

Dejo debajo mi código.

```js
let senteceCy = 'Merry Christmas';
let cypherTxt = '';

for(let i = 0; i < senteceCy.length; i++){
let numLetter = senteceCy.charCodeAt(i);
let cyFormula;
let newLetter;
  if(numLetter>= 65 && numLetter<= 90){
    cyFormula = (numLetter - 65 + 15)%26 + 65;
    newLetter = String.fromCharCode(cyFormula);
    cypherTxt += newLetter;
   }else if(numLetter >= 97 && numLetter <= 122){
    cyFormula = (numLetter - 97 +15)%26 + 97;
    newLetter = String.fromCharCode(cyFormula);
    cypherTxt = cypherTxt + newLetter;
   }
}
console.log(cypherTxt);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Faltaría incluir una condicional para identificar a los espacios en tu cadena, es decir, cuando identifica el espacio, genera un espacio en el string final:

```
else if(numLetter === 32){
    cypherTxt += ' ';
}
```

Código:

```js
let senteceCy = 'Merry Christmas';
let cypherTxt = '';

for (let i = 0; i < senteceCy.length; i++) {
  let numLetter = senteceCy.charCodeAt(i);
  let cyFormula;
  let newLetter;
  if (numLetter >= 65 && numLetter <= 90) {
    cyFormula = ((numLetter - 65 + 15) % 26) + 65;
    newLetter = String.fromCharCode(cyFormula);
    cypherTxt += newLetter;
  } else if (numLetter >= 97 && numLetter <= 122) {
    cyFormula = ((numLetter - 97 + 15) % 26) + 97;
    newLetter = String.fromCharCode(cyFormula);
    cypherTxt = cypherTxt + newLetter;
  } else if (numLetter === 32) {
    cypherTxt += ' ';
  }
}
console.log(cypherTxt);
```

Answer (score 5):

Basándome en lo que menciona el título: simplemente te falta contemplar el ASCII del espacio (32) en tu `if`.

```js
let senteceCy = 'Merry Christmas';
let cypherTxt = '';

for(let i = 0; i < senteceCy.length; i++){
let numLetter = senteceCy.charCodeAt(i);
let cyFormula;
let newLetter;
  if(numLetter>= 65 && numLetter<= 90){
    cyFormula = (numLetter - 65 + 15)%26 + 65;
    newLetter = String.fromCharCode(cyFormula);
    cypherTxt += newLetter;
   }else if(numLetter >= 97 && numLetter <= 122){
    cyFormula = (numLetter - 97 +15)%26 + 97;
    newLetter = String.fromCharCode(cyFormula);
    cypherTxt = cypherTxt + newLetter;
   }
   else if(numLetter == 32) {
    newLetter = String.fromCharCode(numLetter);
    cypherTxt += newLetter;       
   }
}
console.log(cypherTxt);
```

Para el caso de los caracteres especiales, es nada más un `else`.

```js
let senteceCy = 'Merry Christmas ▲▼';
let cypherTxt = '';

for(let i = 0; i < senteceCy.length; i++){
let numLetter = senteceCy.charCodeAt(i);
let cyFormula;
let newLetter;
  if(numLetter>= 65 && numLetter<= 90){
    cyFormula = (numLetter - 65 + 15)%26 + 65;
    newLetter = String.fromCharCode(cyFormula);
    cypherTxt += newLetter;
   }else if(numLetter >= 97 && numLetter <= 122){
    cyFormula = (numLetter - 97 +15)%26 + 97;
    newLetter = String.fromCharCode(cyFormula);
    cypherTxt = cypherTxt + newLetter;
   }
   else {
    newLetter = String.fromCharCode(numLetter);
    cypherTxt += newLetter;       
   }
}
console.log(cypherTxt);
```

Comment: Ya que el cifrado de cesar solo es para letras del alfabeto, la más correcta sería la segunda.

Comment: @rexxarcat Sí, por eso hice la aclaración. En el título menciona solo espacios, pero en la pregunta como tal menciona además a los caracteres especiales.

Comment: Verdad, toda la razon.

Comment: @padaleiana muchisimas gracias!!! You made my day! : )